# JSX props should not use .bind()

Tags: reactjs, jsx, function-binding

How to fix this error when I have the binding this way: previously binding in constructor solved but this is a bit complex for me:

```
{this.onClick.bind(this, 'someString')}>
```

and

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
```

Answer (score 44):

Option 1:

Use `arrow functions` (with babel-plugins) 
PS:- Experimental feature

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   handleClick = (args) => () => {
      // access args here;
      // handle the click event
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div onClick={this.handleClick(args)}>
         .....
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

Option 2: Not recommended

Define arrow functions in render

```
   class MyComponent extends Component {
       render() {
         const handleClick = () => {
          // handle the click event
         }
         return (
           <div onClick={handleClick}>
             .....
           </div>
         )
       }
     }
```

Option 3:

Use binding in constructor

```
   class MyComponent extends Component {
       constructor() {
         super();
         this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
       }

       handleClick() {
          // handle click
       }

       render() {

         return (
           <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
             .....
           </div>
         )
       }
     }
```

Comment: The first option is called ["class property"](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and it's an experimental babel plugin

Comment: @PaoloMoretti yes, thats right. I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it

Comment: How do you pass arguments with the first option?

Comment: yea, the main issue I have is how do I pass the arguments? I am already doing Option3 in my code for other simpler functions...

Comment: @shota  updated now, use closures to solve the problem

Comment: That looks cool. Will the first argument of the closure be event object (for example to get input value)?

Comment: Second function has the event, `handleClick = (args) => (event) => {...}`

Comment: Option 1 will create a new function every time.

Comment: @Brandon It will create the function in each render if its defined inside render function. In option 1 it wont

Comment: With Option 3, how would you pass in parameters?

Comment: @theineffablebob need to make handleClick as a closure, handleClick => (arg) => (event) => {} and call as this.handleClick(arg)

Comment: binding in constructor is the best practice.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you to use binding in the class constructor. This will avoid inline repetition (and confusion) and will execute the "bind" only once (when component is initiated).

Here's an example how you can achieve cleaner JSX in your use-case:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Bind functions
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.onClick('someString');
    }
    onClick(param) {
        // That's your 'onClick' function
        // param = 'someString'
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        // Same here.
        this.handleFormSubmit();
    }
    handleFormSubmit() {
        // That's your 'handleFormSubmit' function
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <p>...</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit">Go!</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work - infinite loop - bundle.js:10623 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: Hey @monkeyjs , I just updated my answer with a code example for your use-case. Please try this way. If you again receive the same error, the issue is somewhere else. Then please share more complete code example and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Even though all the previous answers can achieve the desire result, but I think the snippet below worth mentioning.

```js
class myComponent extends PureComponent {

  handleOnclickWithArgs = arg => {...};

  handleOnclickWithoutArgs = () => {...};

  render() {
    const submitArg = () => this.handleOnclickWithArgs(arg);
    const btnProps = { onClick: submitArg }; // or onClick={submitArg} will do

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button {...btnProps}>button with argument</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleOnclickWithoutArgs}>
          button without argument
        </button>
     </Fragment>
   );
  }
}
```